# How to let Ubuntu index and find files on a different (Windows) drive when searching?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search, lenses

I love the Unity dash and lenses, but it only finds files that are under /home/mylogin

I would like it to find files that are under /media/MyWindowsDrive/Users/MyWinLogin

I tried creating a link to the Music, Pictures and Video folders on my Windows driver and putting the link in the corresponding folders in /home/mylogin , but this doesn't cause Ubuntu (the dash) to index and find these files.

Is this possible?

Comment: Note: the exception is Music, this DOES work after letting Rhythmbox index all my music.  This is in 12.04 (fully updated)

Answer (score 13):

You can perhaps index the files on a different drive using [tracker-gui](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/tracker-gui) [image: Install tracker-gui].

Install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install tracker-gui
```

After installing it, open it and go to *Locations* tab. Click on the + button and add whichever drive or specific directory that you want to index.

It goes without saying that the drive has to be mounted already to be able to be indexed.

[image]

Comment: awesome. any way to see indexing progress?

Comment: @eggonlegs I am not too sure about it. You can perhaps try to estimate if a folder is indexed by searching for a file in the folder..