# How do I search files from a different partition using the dash

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-dash, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to let Ubuntu index and find files on a different (Windows) drive when searching?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116651/how-to-let-ubuntu-index-and-find-files-on-a-different-windows-drive-when-searc)

I recently created a soft link to my Windows music folder so that whenever I click the music folder on Wbuntu, it'll take me to my music on Windows. Whenever I try to search my music using the dash though, nothing pops up. Is there a way to index these files so that they are included when I try to search my music?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called tracker-gui mentioned on the answer for this question:
[How to let Ubuntu index and find files on a different (Windows) drive when searching?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116651/how-to-let-ubuntu-index-and-find-files-on-a-different-windows-drive-when-searc)